# How to enable mod_proxy_ajp for Apache 2.2.14?

Tags: apache2, apache2-module

I have Apache 2.1.14 installed and running in production - due to a new requirement, I need to start using the module mod_proxy_ajp.

Running the './httpd -l' script does not show the compiled module 'mod_proxy_ajp'.

Is there a way I can enable mod_proxy_ajp withough having to recompile the Apache instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

sudo a2enmod proxy_ajp